# shell script for checking files in a directory with count

Tags: unix

Iam trying to write a shell script to check the files in a particular path ,
if files available then i need to get success mail else I need to get failure mail .
but I my query even if 1 file is available I am getting success mail but daily I am getting 9 files , even if 1 file is not available I need to get failure mail please help me to write a script for the above logic

```
cd /file path 
if [ -f $(date '+%Y%m%d') file name ]; then
echo "Hi Team,  Input Files have been received successfully" |  mailx -s "SUCCESS" -r "FILE_CHK" userid@doamin.com
else
echo "Hi Team,  Input Files have NOT been received . Please check" |  mailx -s "FAILED" -r "FILE_CHK" userid@doamin.com
fi
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that all the files exist and only if this is the case send the mail that it was successful. If you have only one file not present, then you should directly send the error message.

The following code prototype does the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=( "file1" "file2" "file3" )
for i in "${files[@]}"
do
    echo "Checking if file: $i exists."
    if [ ! -f $i ]; then
        echo "Hi Team, Input File $i has NOT been received! Please check" |  mailx -s "FAILED" -r "FILE_CHK" userid@doamin.com
        exit 0;
    fi
done
echo "Hi Team, Input Files have been received successfully" |  mailx -s "SUCCESS" -r "FILE_CHK" userid@doamin.com
```

Basically you have a list of files you need to check, you check **element by element** that it does exist and if one of the element of the list is not present then you send **the failure notification by mail and you exit**.

**If and only if all the files are present then you send the success message!!!**

*Last but not least, this script is just a skeleton that you need to adapt to your particular needs (adding a timestamp etc).*